# How to properly deserialize a string from JQuery using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, string, serialization

I was wondering, does anyone know how do I properly deserialize a string from a JQuery using PHP?  The string that JQuery passes into my PHP file is this:

age_gender=1&age_gender=2&age_gender=3&age_gender=4&age_gender=5&age_gender=6

The values I need are the numbers after the equal signs (they are just dummy values that I used for testing).

EDIT: Actually, I am already using parse_str().  Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['age_gender'])) { 
    $formSerialized = $_POST['age_gender'];
    $formData = array();
    parse_str($formSerialized, $formData);
    addRow($formData, $link); 
}

function addRow($dataArray, $link) {
    $age_group = $dataArray[0];
    $populations = array(intval($dataArray[1]) + intval($dataArray[2]), intval($dataArray[1]), intval($dataArray[2]));
    $percents = array(doubleval($dataArray[3]) + doubleval($dataArray[4]), doubleval($dataArray[3]), doubleval($dataArray[4]));
    $m_per_100_f = doubleval($dataArray[6]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO national_age_gender_demographics (age_group, both_pop, male_pop, female_pop, both_percent, male_percent, female_percent, males_per_100_females)
    VALUES ('$age_group','$populations[0]','$populations[1]','$populations[2]','$percents[0]','$percents[1]','$percents[2]','$m_per_100_f')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    if(!$result)  die( "Query: " . $query . "\nError:" . mysql_error() );
}
```

For some reason, I am getting a blank string for $age_group, and 0's for all other values.  Could anyone help me here?

Comment: ever tried $_REQUEST['fieldname']?

Comment: If this string is the `data` of jQuery AJAX request then the server decodes them automatically into an array which is available in `$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on the `type` of AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

See [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Example:

```
parse_str('age_gender=1&age_gender=2&age_gender=3&age_gender=4&age_gender=5&age_gender=6', $output); 
print_r($output);
```

Also if you want to get the querystring of the request you can get it with php using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: The next thing I aimed at doing after that comment was `parse_str()`.. you beat me to it :D

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) 
is the function you are looking for.
You have two options to use with this:

1. `parse_str($string)` - this will actually create a variable for each key in the string.
2. `parse_str($string,$arr)` - this will populate `$arr` with an associative array containing all the key=>value pairs from the string.

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) gives some great code to demonstrate this behavior:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Comment: Actually, I am already using parse_str().  Here is my php code:
`

Comment: You should actually update your original post with the code you're using.